# How are persistent database connections stored in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, caching, persistence

As stated in the documentation on [sqlite_popen](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-popen.php) php tries to make use of a persistent resource mechanism. Where is this mechanism described in detail? Is it possible to view all resources currently stored/used? Is it possible to access this mechanism and store/read other values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sqlite_popen uses the (executor) global hashtable "persistent_list" to store the connection resource. This hashtable is not part of the php "instance" which executes your script but of the php "runtime", which means it's not cleared/removed after the script is done but held in memory as long as the php .so/.dll/fastcgi.exe.
You cannot access EG(persistent_list) from within a php script but any php module/extension can.

Comment: Although I somehow hoped to have more control over the list this is exactly what I was looking for. More information can be found here http://eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index/html/php/Sams.Advanced.PHP.Programming.Feb.2004.INTERNAL/0672325616/ch20lev1sec4.html Which seems to be an excerpt from "Sams Advanced PHP Programming".